# django csv import threading

Tags: python, django, multithreading, csv

Is it possible to use threading when importing data from csv files to django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django is Python, so yeah you can use threads, processing etc. Look at python docs on this matter.

But, spawning threads in web environment might be not be such a good idea, try searching here for "django asynchronous" - you'll get many ideas of how to this without threading.